# Why does a jar file work differently with and without console?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, console, cmd

I obtain different results using the same program when I run it thru:
1)..\Desktop\app.jar
2)..\Desktop\java -jar app.jar
second case gives the same result that I saw in eclipse but it uses console.
Question is: How do I force my program to work properly (to give the same result as in eclipse) by direct executing app.jar (without console)?

Comment: When you say properly I assume you mean get a console window to show when the jar is executed?

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You'll have to make your own console using swing or something.

Comment: Please post SSCCE sscce.org

Comment: When I say properlt I mean work the same way as in eclipse.
and I really don't need a console while it running.
SSCCE is not possible because it's a big project and I can not find the problem because I need at least console for tracking but when I start to use console it starts to work perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `javaw` instead of `java` in command line:

```
..\Desktop\javaw -jar app.jar
```

More information: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/java.html

Comment: Thanks. this solved my problem.
Is it possible to make the call "\javaw -jar app.jar" using dobble clicking on .jar file?

Comment: that is good but my program should work in any other computer and I think it's not a good idea to change windows settings for the doubleclicking on every PC. Also it's not good to force users to start it thru command line.

Is it bossible to indicate this information somewhere in .jar package or I necessarily have to make batch files for that?

Comment: You can create a batch file or you can wrap a jar into exe, but this will work for Windows only. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file